# data.slice is not a function React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, recharts

im trying to get api data into a chart in react js i was using a local array to use like sample values

now im trying to pass an api data to inside the chart but i get the data.slice is not a function error and i dont know why, someone here can help me?

PS: i call the function inside an use effect hook

function

```
 const getPeso = async () => {
    const jwt = sessionStorage.getItem('Token')
    const user = jwtDecode(jwt)



    const token = sessionStorage.getItem('Token')
    console.log(token)
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/animals/animal/client?clientId=" + user.id, {
        method: "get",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": `${token}`,
        },
    })
    const data = await response.json();
    setPeso(data)

};
```

Chart

```
 <div className='pesoGraph'>
        <h1>Pesagem</h1>
        <a>Mês</a>
        <a style={Styles}>Ano</a>
        <LineChart
            width={650}
            height={300}
            data={setPeso}
            margin={{
                top: 20,
                right: 50,
                left: 50,
                bottom: 70
            }}
        >
            <CartesianGrid vertical={false} />
            <XAxis dataKey="data" axisLine={false} tickLine={false} tickMargin={10} color={'#494949'} fontWeight={'500'} />
            <YAxis dataKey='peso' domain={['dataMin', 'dataMax']} tickCount={4} axisLine={false} tickLine={false} tickMargin={10} color={'#494949'} fontWeight={'500'} />
            <Tooltip />

            <Line
                type="monotone"
                dataKey="peso"
                stroke="#000000"
                activeDot={{ r: 8 }}
            />
        </LineChart>
    </div>
```

Comment: `slice` is an array-method. It works only on arrays (it won't work on objects).

Comment: What is `setPeso`?

Comment: first check your data in console , do you receive that ? or add dependency item to useEffect.

Comment: const [setPeso] = useState([]);

Comment: @mazdak i receive the data in console

Comment: Try `const [peso, setPeso] = useState([]);` And write a `console.log(data)` after `const data = await response.json();` and make sure `data` (printed value) is an array.

Comment: @AjeetShah i should convert my object to an array?

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: @User007 Does it print an array or object?

Comment: prints an array of objects

Comment: maybe the response data is not in the correct format as Linechar expect

Answer (score 0):

From this line  `setPeso(data)` it is clear that  `setPeso(data)` is a function.

You are then passing it to the chart component:

```
 <LineChart
        width={650}
        height={300}
        data={setPeso} // <-- here
```

Based on the error message the chart component is expecting an array as data.
Your code should be something like

```
const [peso, setPeso] = useState([]);
// ... other code
<LineChart
        width={650}
        height={300}
        data={peso}
```

where `peso` is an array in state.

Comment: i did that but since peso is an empty array it dont appear nothing on the chart

Comment: @User007 it'll appear once you do `setPeso(data)` after API call if that code works correctly. Response data should be an array in the format line chart component expects

Comment: i did that the chart is still empty

Comment: Please make a codesandbox with sample data from api

Comment: @User007 Are you ever calling `getPeso()` which does the `fetch()` request?